# CakePHP2.x Plugin consisting of single Pages view

Tags: cakephp

My understanding of the CakePHP2 doc leads me to believe I can create a simple plugin that consists of a single view and that view can (if done correctly) override the default view.

For example, if the application has a app/View/Pages/foo.ctp that simply displays the text "Foo", then a Plugin in app/Plugin/Bar/View/Pages/foo.ctp that contains the text "Bar"

I've made sure that the bootstrap.php loads the plugin with CakePlugin::load('Bar');

And I've deleted app/tmp/cache/*/*

From what I understand I'm not required by Cake to need a Controller or Model.

Yet, the application only displays "Foo" instead of the intended override of displaying "Bar".

From what I've described, what parts of my understanding or implementation approach seem wrong? (And why?) And what are the simple/better ways to implement this plugin view?

TIA

(I have read http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins.html and http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Themes?

A [theme](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/themes.html) is just a collection of template files that can be used to override the templates used in an application; whereas [plugins](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins.html) also contain classes - are you looking for themes?

### Creating a template in a plugin is not enough

Alone is not sufficient to just create a template file and load a plugin. To render it you'll need to either:

#### Explicitly render the file

I.e. In any controller:

```
$this->render('Bar.template_name')
```

#### Create an actual plugin

I.e. Create plugin files:

```
$ Console\cake bake plugin Bar
$ Console\cake bake controller Some --plugin Bar
$ etc.
$ echo "Something" > Plugin/Bar/View/Some/index.ctp
```

And request: `http://yourapp.com/bar/index`

See [the docs on how to create a plugin](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins/how-to-create-plugins.html) for more information.

Comment: The challenge in this seems to be the requirement to use Cakes Plugin features, and also that the URL can't change before/after Plugin enabling.  Until either of those changes, Plugins it has to be and foo/index it has to stay.  So I need to exhaust that approach before making a case for something else in order to get requirements changed.

Comment: I have no idea what you're doing =). Is this some academic challenge? Why do you need to make a case for something instead of achieving what you've asked? Alternatively: your understanding of the docs is not correct.

Comment: Not academic. Someone with no Plugin experience tasked someone with no Plugin experience (me) ... to achieve use of plugins with a view  and not change the URL.  Your response was educational, but outside of the original post problem space (I'm not being hostile/ingrateful).  Once this is solved, I'll be glad to post back what the end solution turned out to be once I figure it out with or without kind assistance.  Perhaps 3 hours reading doc and trying examples isn't adequate baseline for me.  From what I read/understand no model, no controller is required.

Comment: `to achieve use of plugins [..] and not change the URL` - That's just route definitions. `From what I read/understand no model, no controller is required.` - I don't know exactly what you've read to draw that conclusion - it doesn't work like that. Unless I've somehow misunderstood your question, you _aren't_ going to find some way to do exactly what you've asked; you cannot render a plugin view, without directly or indirectly asking to render a plugin view.

Comment: AD7six, I had misread this ** Inside the plugin folder, you’ll notice it looks a lot like a CakePHP application, and that’s basically what it is. You don’t actually have to include any of those folders if you do not use them. Some plugins might only define a Component and a Behavior, ....**  so I skipped over the next part **If you want to be able to access your plugin with a URL, defining an AppController and AppModel for the plugin is required.**  Thanks.  You answered my original questions.  Yes, routes will have to be part of it if the URL is to appear unchanged. Thx.